# Check how much extended alignment is supported

Tags: c++, c++14, memory-alignment

I am implementing a templated class that allows the client to set the alignment of some inner data.

I am going to allocate the data with `std::align`. The [documentation reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/align) "the behavior is undefined if alignment is not a fundamental or extended alignment value supported by the implementation (until C++17)".

`alignof(std::max_align_t)` gives me the maximum fundamental alignment, but is there any platform-independent way of checking if a value is a supported extended alignment in C++14 to protect me against undefined behavior?

If not, should I do without `std::align` and do the alignment by myself?

Comment: How do you intend to do the alignment yourself?  Conversion from pointer to integer values is also implementation defined...

Comment: @ChronoTrigger: Considering that compilers do not have to support extended alignment at all and `alignas` does not signal success or failure, I think there is no way this check can be done.